# Maximal and minimal eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

> Given $m \times m$ symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 4 & 1 &  & \\ 1 & 4 & \ddots & \\  & \ddots & \ddots &  1\\ &  & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}, \qquad A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 &  & \\ -1 & 2 & \ddots & \\ & \ddots & \ddots & -1\\ &  & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$ determine the maximal and minimal eigenvalues of $$F = M + h^{-\alpha} A$$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}, h=\frac{1}{m+1}$ when $\mu_j = 4 + 2\cos(jh\pi)$ are the eigenvalues of $M$ and $\eta_j = 2 - 2\cos(jh\pi)$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ with $j=1,\dots, m$.

---

I guess it is $\lambda_j=4+2\cos(jh\pi) + h^{-\alpha}(2-2\cos(jh\pi))$ but I cannot show it. To determine the eigenvalues of

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 1 &  & \\
1 & 4 & \ddots & \\
 & \ddots & \ddots &  1\\
&  & 1 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I used the ansatz $\det(M-\mu_jI)=\det(J-(\mu_j-4)I)$ with

$$J=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 &  & \\
1 & 0 & \ddots & \\
 & \ddots & \ddots &  1\\
&  & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for which the eigenvalues are $\sigma_j=2\cos(jh\pi)$ and I hope $\mu_j=4+2\cos(jh\pi)$ is correct! The eigenvalues of $A$ were already given. The maximal eigenvalue of $M$ is $\mu_1$ but the maximal eigenvalue of $A$ is $\eta_m$.

I need to show that the spectral condition $\kappa(F)=\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}$ in first approximation of $h$ (means with the big O notation) is $$\kappa(F)\sim \begin{cases}
3-6h^{-\alpha}, \alpha \leq -1\\
1, \alpha=0 \text{ (done})\\
\frac{2}{3}h^{-1}, \alpha=1 \\
\frac{4}{6+\pi^2}h^{-2}, \alpha=2 \\
\frac{4}{\pi^2}h^{-2}, \alpha\geq 3 
\end{cases}$$

Consider $\alpha \leq -1$, then it is $$\kappa(F)=\frac{\lambda_{\max}}{\lambda_{\min}}=\frac{4+2h^{-\alpha} +2\cos(\pi h)(1-h^{-\alpha})}{4+2h^{-\alpha} -2\cos(\pi h)\,(1-h^{-\alpha})} \sim \frac{4+2h^{-\alpha} +2(1-h^{-\alpha})}{4+2h^{-\alpha} -2\,(1-h^{-\alpha})} $$
since $$cos(h\pi)=1-O(h^2)$$ with $\alpha \leq -1$. I cannot show that $\kappa(F)=3-6h^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha\leq -1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the notation $$M=4I+J,\quad A=2I-J$$ Therefore
$$ M+h^{-\alpha}A  =(4+2h^{-\alpha})\,I +(1-h^{-\alpha})\,J$$ Every eigenvalue of $M+h^{-\alpha}A$ is thus of the form $$ [4+2h^{-\alpha}]+(1-h^{-\alpha})\, \lambda\qquad (*)$$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $J.$ The eigenvalues of $J$ are known, and are listed in the question. That's actually  a nontrivial fact which follows from the trigonometric identity
$$2\cos \theta\,\sin k\theta= \sin (k+1)\theta+ \sin (k-1)\theta$$ for $\theta $ satisfying $\sin(m+1)\theta =0.$

In the question it is assumed that $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}.$ I will consider $\alpha>0.$
Hence $h^{-\alpha}>1$ and by $(*)$
the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ corresponds to the minimal eigenvalue $\sigma_{\min}$ of $J,$ and the minimal one $\lambda_{\min}$ to the maximal eigenvalue $\sigma_{\max}$ of $J.$
We have
$$\sigma_{\max}=2\cos{\pi\over m}=2\cos \pi h,\qquad \sigma_{\min}=2\cos{\pi(m-1)\over m}=-\sigma_\max$$
The ratio $\lambda_{\max}/\lambda_{\min}$ is thus equal
$$\displaylines{{4+2h^{-\alpha} -2\cos {\pi h}\,(1-h^{-\alpha}) \over 4+2h^{-\alpha} +2\cos {\pi h}\,(1-h^{-\alpha}) }={2+4h^\alpha +2\cos {\pi h}\,(1-h^{\alpha}) \over 2+ 4h^\alpha -2\cos {\pi h}\,(1-h^{\alpha})}\\ =
{4+2h^\alpha-2(1-\cos\pi h)(1-h^\alpha )\over 6h^\alpha+2(1-\cos\pi h)(1-h^\alpha )}}$$
Applying $$2(1-\cos x)={x^2}+O(x^4),\qquad x\to 0,$$  gives
$$ \displaylines{4+2h^\alpha-2(1-\cos\pi h)(1-h^\alpha )=4+2h^\alpha -\pi^2h^2+O(h^{2+\alpha})+O(h^4)\\
=\begin{cases}4+2h^\alpha +O(h^2) & \alpha<2\\
4+(2-\pi^2)h^2+O(h^4) &\alpha=2\\
4 -\pi^2h^2+O(h^\alpha) &\alpha>2
\end{cases}}
$$
Next
$$ \displaylines{6h^\alpha+2(1-\cos\pi h)(1-h^\alpha )=6h^\alpha +\pi^2h^2+O(h^{2+\alpha})+O(h^4)\\
=\begin{cases}6h^\alpha +O(h^2) & \alpha<2\\
(6+\pi^2)h^2+O(h^4) &\alpha=2\\
\pi^2h^2+O(h^\alpha) &\alpha>2
\end{cases}}$$
Therefore
$${\lambda_\max\over \lambda_\min}=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle {2\over 3}h^{-\alpha} +O(1) &\alpha <2\\
\displaystyle {4\over 6+\pi^2}h^{-2}+O(1) & \alpha=2\\
\displaystyle {4\over \pi^2}h^{-2} +O(1) & \alpha>2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! I used $det(F_{\alpha}-\nu_jI)=det((1-h^{-\alpha})J-(\nu_j-4-2h^{-\alpha})I)$, so it holds $(1-h^{-\alpha})\lambda_j=\nu_j-4-2h^{-\alpha} \Rightarrow \nu_j=(4+2h^{-\alpha})+(1-h^{-\alpha})\lambda_j$. It is $\lambda_{max}$ for $j=1$ and $\lambda_{min}$ for $j=m$, right?

Comment: That's right $\lambda_\max$ corresponds to the largest eigenvalue of $J,$ i.e. to  $j=1.$ Similarly $\lambda_\min$ corresponds to $j=m.$

Comment: I made an edit at the end of my question referring to the maximal and minimal eigenvalue. Do you know how to show this for $\kappa(F)$? I only get a long fraction with the only difference $cos(\pi h)$ in the numerator and $cos(m\pi h)$ in the denominator which I cannot reduce...

Comment: @Uhmm Sorry, I made a mistake. As the coefficient of $J$ in the expression for $F$ is negative then $\lambda_{\max}$ corresponds to the smallest eigenvalue of $J.$ I have re-edited my answer.

Comment: @Uhmm I got the limit $3$ for any $\alpha>0.$ It is included at the end of the answer. Hopefully there are no errors.

Comment: Consider $\sigma_j=(1-h^{-\alpha}) \lambda_j=\lambda_j - h^{-\alpha}\lambda_j $, the first term is maximal for maximal $\lambda_j$, so $j=1$ but the second term is maximal for minimal  $\lambda_j$, so $j=m$. So you need two different $j$? And I still have no idea how to prove the cases at the end of my question. I don't know if we have to consider $m\rightarrow \infty$ or just use the big O notation as I did at the end by rewriting cosinus... Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Uhmm I have found an error. Now the ratio of the eigenvalues should be correct. I will doublecheck my answer tonight and determine the asymptotic behaviour of the ratio.

Comment: The coefficient $(1-h^{-\alpha})$ of $J$ is negative for $\alpha\leq - 1$, so only in this case is the maximal eigenvalue of $F$ is the minimal one of $J$, so $j=m$. In the other cases it's $j=1$ right?

Comment: No it's the other way around since $h=\frac{1}{m+1}$, $m\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136119/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-uhmm).